# Projectile: project view

Tags: projectile, cedet

Is there a way to have a buffer with a project view i.e. Project file tree?

I have seen this before in Emacs but unsure if this is related to projectile or cedet though. Although I have a feeling there should be something in projectile. If I am not mistaken, cedet is not being used so often anymore.

Answer (score 1):

[neotree](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree) seems to offer the functionality you're after.

It's the Emacs-y version of Vim's [nerdtree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) and lets you see/navigate the files/sub-directories of a specific directory in tree-like fashion.